# how to pass php parameter in datepicker function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I want to pass php value as parameter in datepicker function.
Fuction called perfetly in text box but not in datepicker.when I include datepicker library function is not called.I want to call the function with php value as parameter.Now function is not called.I want to call the function in datepicker onselect event.

```
   #Function called perfectly 
   echo '<td><input type="text" name="interview" class="interview" value="'.$cfet['interview'].'" onblur=place(this.value,'.$cfet['r_id'].',"interview");></td>';

   #problem with datepicker
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="interview" id="datepicker1" class="interview" value="'.$cfet['interview'].'" onselect=place(this.value,'.$cfet['r_id'].',"interview");></td>';
```

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: can you post the rendered HTML too. i guess the isssue might be with the quotes.

Comment: function is not called..

Comment: onblur,onchange is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the datepicker library you use, cause often they have those events directly.

**Example with JQuery Datepicker:**

Change HTML to :

`echo '<td><input type="text" name="interview" id="datepicker1" class="interview" value="'.$cfet['interview'].'" data-r_id="'.$cfet['r_id'].'"></td>';`

JS Code

```
 $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
           place($(this).val(),$(this).data('r_id'),"interview");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

INPUT NOT TRIGGERED "ONSELECT" EVENT

You must set that listener on datepicker object